# Read csv file using 2d array

Tags: c++, file, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file using 2d array but there's a problem with the reading. The first cell of the file is skipped and then continues read all. I don't understand why it doesn't read the first cell.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string arrival,job[3][4];
  ifstream jobfile("myfile.csv");
  std::string fileCommand;

  if(jobfile.is_open())
  {
      cout << "Successfully open file"<<endl;

      while(getline(jobfile,arrival,','))
      {
        for(int i=1;i < 4;i++) //i = no. of job
        {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) // j = no. of processes
            {
                getline(jobfile,job[i][j],',');
                cout << "Job[" << i << "]P[" << j << "]: "<< job[i][j]<< endl;
            }

        }//end for
      }//end while
  }//end if for jobfile open
  jobfile.close();    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `i` to start at 1 ?

Comment: why you start `i` index from 1??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: Try changing `for(int i=1;i < 4;i++)` to `for(int i=0;i < 3;i++)` and see what happens. You are accessing the array `job[3][4]` out of bounds. Also, `jobfile.close();` isn't needed, the `ifstream` object has a destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for(int i=1;i < 3;i++)
```

to this:

```
for(int i=0;i < 3;i++)
```

Also, remove this `getline(jobfile,job[i][j],',');`, since you skip a line that way. When you called getline in the condition of the while loop, it already read a line (as a result, now, you have to store that line. Then, when the condition of the while loop is evaluated again, the next line will be read).

---

However, it gets much more complicated than this, since you `arrival` will hold one token at a time, until it meets the last token of the current line. In that case, `arrival` will be this: `"currentLineLastToken\nnextLineFirstToken"`.

For that reason, you need to specially handle the case that arrival contains a newline, use [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) for this.

When a newline is found, you should split that string to that newline, in order to extract the two tokens involved. Use [`string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) for this.

Moreover, you shouldn't loop inside the while loop with a double for to store the token, you just read. Use a double for loop, when it is time to print `job`, only after exiting the while loop that read the file.

Putting everything together, we get this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string arrival,job[3][4];
  ifstream jobfile("myfile.csv");
  std::string fileCommand;

  if(jobfile.is_open())
  {
      cout << "Successfully open file"<<endl;

      int i = 0, j = 0;
      while(getline(jobfile,arrival,','))
      {
        //cout << "|" << arrival << "|" << endl;
        size_t found = arrival.find("\n");
        if (found != std::string::npos) // if newline was found
        {
                string lastToken = arrival.substr(0, found);
                string nextLineFirstTOken = arrival.substr(found + 1);
                job[i++][j] = lastToken;
                j = 0;
                if(nextLineFirstTOken != "\n") // when you read the last token of the last line
                        job[i][j++] = nextLineFirstTOken;
        }
        else
        {
                job[i][j++] = arrival;
        }

      }//end while

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
                cout << job[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
      }

  }//end if for jobfile open
  jobfile.close();
}
```

Output (for my custom input):

```
Successfully open file
aa bb cc dd 
bla blu blo ble 
qq ww ee rr
```